# 2010 Kia soul car not staying on after removing jumper cables

Tags: electrical, battery, alternator, kia, soul

Car wouldn’t start so used jumper cables to start car.  However, after removing jumper cables lights dimmed then car died.  2nd try Jump starting car removed cables and was able to keep car running but as soon as put in drive noticed my headlights went out followed by the lights dimming and then car died.  No power while steering or gas when  interior lights dimmed out either.  I replaced my car battery last summer and lately been charging more electric item like cell phone, iPad, chargers and cooling fans.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

More than likely your alternator has gone out. If you have the means to charge the battery using a charger, get it up to full charge (which should be 12.5vdc or better). Then start the car and put a multimeter onto the battery. If the voltage continues to drop while the car is running, the alternator is at fault.